# Improve postgre sql select request execution time

Tags: postgresql, select, time, request, execution

I'm trying to improve the execution time for this select request which takes 3s to complete. Mesure_capteur table has ~2 Millions rows and Capteur 400. I added index for Capteur.nom_capteur and Mesure_Capteur.id_capteur. It tooks 10 seconds before doing this but I know what to do after.

```
SELECT C.nom_capteur, mC.horodateur, mC.valeur_mesure_capteur
FROM Mesure_Capteur mC INNER JOIN Capteur C 
    ON mC.id_capteur = C.id_capteur
WHERE C.nom_capteur = 'ENEEANABatterie005'
    AND mC.horodateur between '2017-10-15 00:00:00' and '2017-10-15 01:00:00'
ORDER BY mC.horodateur DESC
```

Here are my two tables:

```
create table Capteur(
    id_capteur int  primary key,
    nom_capteur varchar(180),
    description_capteur varchar(100),
    id_sous_systeme int,
    description_unite varchar(50),
    unite varchar(10),
    seuil_min real,
    seuil_max real,
    FOREIGN KEY (id_sous_systeme) REFERENCES Sous_systeme(id_sous_systeme)
);
```

-

```
create table Mesure_capteur(
    id_mesure_capteur  serial PRIMARY KEY,
    valeur_mesure_capteur NUMERIC(20,2),
    id_capteur int,
    FOREIGN KEY (id_capteur) REFERENCES Capteur(id_capteur),
    horodateur abstime
);
```

Here's the explain analyze:

```
'Sort  (cost=352931.30..352931.30 rows=1 width=25) (actual time=3147.592..3147.625 rows=494 loops=1)'
'  Sort Key: mc.horodateur DESC'
'  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 51kB'
'  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=3361.03..352931.29 rows=1 width=25) (actual time=1485.653..3147.419 rows=494 loops=1)'
'        ->  Index Scan using capteur_nom_capteur_index on capteur c  (cost=0.27..8.29 rows=1 width=22) (actual time=0.045..0.047 rows=1 loops=1)'
'              Index Cond: ((nom_capteur)::text = 'ENEEANABatterie005'::text)'
'        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on mesure_capteur mc  (cost=3360.76..352922.99 rows=1 width=11) (actual time=1485.598..3147.304 rows=494 loops=1)'
'              Recheck Cond: (id_capteur = c.id_capteur)'
'              Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 17942069'
'              Filter: ((horodateur >= '2017-10-15 00:00:00+02'::abstime) AND (horodateur <= '2017-10-15 01:00:00+02'::abstime))'
'              Rows Removed by Filter: 181360'
'              Heap Blocks: exact=45030 lossy=99772'
'              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on mesure_capteur_id_capteur_index  (cost=0.00..3360.76 rows=181359 width=0) (actual time=63.333..63.333 rows=181854 loops=1)'
'                    Index Cond: (id_capteur = c.id_capteur)'
'Planning time: 0.367 ms'
'Execution time: 3148.039 ms'
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this query:

```
SELECT C.nom_capteur, mC.horodateur, mC.valeur_mesure_capteur
FROM Mesure_Capteur mC INNER JOIN
     Capteur C
     ON mC.id_capteur = C.id_capteur
WHERE C.nom_capteur = 'ENEEANABatterie005' AND
      mC.horodateur between '2017-10-15 00:00:00' and '2017-10-15 01:00:00'
ORDER BY mC.horodateur DESC;
```

I would recommend indexes on `Mesure_Capteur(horodateur, id_capteur)` and `Capteur(id_capteur, nom_capteur)`.  The latter is not needed if `id_capteur` is already declared as a primary key.

Comment: Thank you very much, execution time is now ~15 ms. 

Do you have any good link where I could learn how to improve execution time with indexes (in order to read it when i'll have time).

Will it affects a lot execution time for insert request ? I insert ~400row/s in the Mesure_capteur table.

Comment: @JoelMP . . . I actually like the MySQL documentation on the subject (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html).  Although indexes vary among databases, the basics are pretty similar.